# How to put in Voltage Dependent Current Source in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

my post lab question asks me to simulate a circuit using LTSpice. I am having trouble implementing it.
The circuit looks like this:

[image]

My issue is with the little diamond thing on the very right. I don't understand how it would be connected in LTSpice, because it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Replace the "G" with "2.5", rotate and flip the source so that you can wire it in pointing correctly, and tie in the (+) and (-) connections to the appropriate nodes on the schematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dependent source is dependent on either a voltage or current. This lets us make feedback loops and other interesting circuits.

With a voltage controlled current source (VCCS) the control voltage comes from voltage source, the inputs to the source draws no current and the current from the source is based on this voltage. In this case the voltage is controlled from the differential voltage across the resistor. Like this:

[image]